# How to formally prove that if $R={0}$, the only R-module is the zero module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, axioms

I think there is something related to the axiom for an R-module $V$, $1v=v$. And for a zero ring since $1=0$ we have $0v=1v$. Hence there maybe a contradiction. But so far, I am not able to find it out.

Am I on the right track of proving it formally? Could someone please give a full prove of that?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. You just need to notice that $0v = 0$ for all $v$ (in any module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that $0_Rv = 0_M$ for every $v \in M$. (Just note $0_R v = (0_R + 0_R)v = 0_Rv + 0_RV$ and thus $0_M = 0_R v$.) 
Since $1_R v = v$, it follows in case $1_R = 0_R$ that $v = 1_R v = 0_R v = 0_M$ for every $v$, whence the claim.

Comment: Thank you! And furthermore, which axiom or theorem tells us that we can cancel $0_{R}v$ on both sides?

Comment: You're welcome. It is because the module with addition is a (commutative) group. You can think of the 'cancelling' as adding the additive inverse of $0_Rv$ to both sides.